# How to show multiple PopupMenu in Metro WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await, popupmenu

How to show multiple PupupMenu looks like below image in Metro/WinRT (C#) ?

[image: Image Multiple PopupMenu]

Here is my C# code.

```
    private async void OnPointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu();
        menu1.Commands.Add(new UICommand("menu1 A", (function) => { }));
        menu1.Commands.Add(new UICommand("menu1 B", (function) => { }));
        Task<IUICommand> task1 = menu1.ShowAsync(new Point(100, 100)).AsTask<IUICommand>();

        PopupMenu menu2 = new PopupMenu();
        menu2.Commands.Add(new UICommand("menu2 C", (function) => { }));
        menu2.Commands.Add(new UICommand("menu2 D", (function) => { }));
        Task<IUICommand> task2 = menu2.ShowAsync(new Point(200, 100)).AsTask<IUICommand>(); // A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

        Task<IUICommand> task = await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2);

        if (task.Result != null)
        {
            await new MessageDialog(task.Result.Label).ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since I'm admittedly too lazy to copy/paste this and try myself: Where does your code fail? If I had to guess, then it's probably impossible to have multiple PopupMenus open at a time - it could break LightDismiss. In this case the solution would be combining all the menu items into one PopupMenu or into a custom control.

Comment: failed at: Task<IUICommand> task2 = menu2.ShowAsync(new Point(200, 100)).AsTask<IUICommand>();

Comment: ooops. sorry, my bad. i didn't scroll to the right ...

Comment: I copied the code. At the second ShowAsync I get a System.InvalidOperationException with the message "A method was called at an unexpected time." So I guess PopupMenu doesn't like multiple instances being shown.

Comment: Those are looking like Flyout menus (not from charm) - search for that. Is this Windows 8 or 8.1 app?

Comment: It's Windows 8 app, Visual Studio 2012, not Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I also tried Flyouts - they don't crash, but only one is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `WinRT` doesn't support displaying multiple popups (it tells you with an exception). That's true for `PopupMenu`, `MessageBox` and more.

You could probably create your own window that looks like a double `PopupMenu` but I would advise against that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if displaying more than one popup menu is possible, but your code is blocking the UI thread by calling `Result` on the task.

Try this instead:

```
private async void OnPointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu();
    menu1.Commands.Add(new UICommand("menu1 A", (function) => { }));
    menu1.Commands.Add(new UICommand("menu1 B", (function) => { }));
    Task<IUICommand> task1 = menu1.ShowAsync(new Point(100, 100)).AsTask<IUICommand>();

    PopupMenu menu2 = new PopupMenu();
    menu2.Commands.Add(new UICommand("menu2 C", (function) => { }));
    menu2.Commands.Add(new UICommand("menu2 D", (function) => { }));
    Task<IUICommand> task2 = menu2.ShowAsync(new Point(200, 100)).AsTask<IUICommand>(); // A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

    Task<IUICommand> task = await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2);

    var res = await task;
    if (res != null)
    {
        await new MessageDialog(res.Label).ShowAsync();
    }

    await Task.WaitAll(task1, task2); // just to await them all
}
```

Comment: He's not blocking. WhenAny returns the first completed task which means that task.Result will return immediately.

Comment: My bad, @I3arnon. But still a dangerous practice.